# Domain with host:port not working with node-fetch

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

```js
const response = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: headers
})
```

Here `API_URL = ​https://139.59.39.54:53724/business/1.0/verify`

Getting error

> TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

I though maybe the problem with package it doesn't support domain with IP addresses, so I also tried [nip.io](https://nip.io/<br><br)
. 
But still getting same error.
**Update**
I am using `dotenv` for environment variables. So If directly use the domain I don't get error any more.

```js
const response = await fetch("​https://139.59.39.54:53724/business/1.0/verify", {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify(body),
     headers: headers
})
```

Comment: is this correct API_URL  ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 139.59.39.56:53724 , as well postman connections failed , please check API url

Comment: Yes, I know the problem is not with the domain, it's working fine. try..

Comment: Change your domain. I mean remove 1.0 from your domain.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing **reading environment variables** with `dotenv`, such as call `require('dotenv').config();`.

Because `dotenv` can understand `API_URL = ​https://139.59.39.54:53724/business/1.0/verify` that `API_URL` is a **string**. Therefore `API_URL` you read from `process.env.API_URL` now is **empty**, which can cause the error.

Please make sure you've called `require('dotenv').config();` ***before*** reading `process.env.API_URL`.

Comment: No that's not the problem, I if log that variable inside the function I am getting the same url.

Comment: can you share full your code? I've made a simple example and it works well :P